# Handling RFID time response functions in C

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, rfid, rtos, renesas

I'm developing an embedded app, writen in C, using a M16C/28 uC from Renesas.

The app manages two simple task:

1. RFID for detection and reading MIFARE tags. ( Using HW: Mf500 from NXP ). The uC handles whole FW implementation.
2. To deal with a RS485 frame protocol as slave. ( This app, have to
   be able to process RS485 frames every 10ms ).

I noticed that due to the RFID implemented blocking code, the time response to detect a RFID tag is about 15ms, so that's the reason because rx reception buffer overflows.

My questions are as follows:

- Is it normal to deal with such time responses in the RFID world?
- Should i use a RTOS to preemt RFID task to meet RS485 frames requierements? - Should i use an external uC acting as host controller to release the load of the RFID manager uC?

Comment: Can you interrupt on RS485 rx? It doesn't sound as though you would need an RTOS, just some interrupts with sensible priorities.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your rapid answer. Yes, i'm using rx interrupts. In the foreground i collect all rs485 data and put it into a circular buffer, then i wrote a task in the background used to process the received frame and send to the master the response.